# TypeScript + Jest + Ts-Jest Error: error when run build script

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

When the script build is executed the prompt return a dependecies error:

```sh
> tsc -p tsconfig.json && rollup -c rollup.config.js

node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:484:51 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jest-diff'.

484             diff(a: any, b: any, options?: import("jest-diff").DiffOptions): string | null;
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:538:44 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'pretty-format'.

538     type SnapshotSerializerPlugin = import('pretty-format').Plugin;
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

More details about versions, errors, etc.
https://github.com/felipesousa/wunderlist-api/tree/develop